# How to replace [tag][/tag] with <tag></tag>?

Tags: php, replace, tags

I have this text:

`Maine mergem in [b]parc[/b].`

How can I replace `[b]` and `[/b]` with `<b>` and `</b>` ?

I tried this:

```
$str = 'Maine mergem in [b]parc[/b].';
$str2 = preg_replace('[b]', '<b>', $str);
echo preg_replace('[/b]', '</b>', $str2);
```

But it gives me this (not what I want):

`Maine mergem in [<b>]parc[/<b>].`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Won't the [b] regex just match just a 'b' character? I think you need to escape the brackets like this '\\[b\\]'.

Comment: If you can install the PECL extension, have a look at PECL's BBCode Class. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using str_replace instead of preg_replace:

```
$str = 'Maine mergem in [b]parc[/b].';
$str2 = str_replace('[b]', '<b>', $str);
echo str_replace('[/b]', '</b>', $str2);
```

Comment: But.. this script replace just a tag, i want all tags to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, i'm a newby in this, but your mistake is that you are not using a character for begginig and end of pattern so it takes '[' and ']'.

you should use {} or // whtaever you want:

```
$str = 'Maine mergem in [b]parc[/b].';
$str2 = preg_replace('{[b]}', '<b>', $str);
echo preg_replace('{[/b]}', '</b>', $str2);
```